# How to get the right execution context during runtime

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, executioncontext, user-event

I'm trying to prevent a userevent script from running in case of a mass update triggering it. Pretty simple task you might think. Usually the runtime.executionContext should give me the value that I'm looking for. What I'm expecting is `runtime.ContextType.CUSTOM_MASSUPDATE` but I keep getting the `runtime.ContextType.USEREVENT`.

What I need is the value that is correctly written in the system notes for this action:[image: see here]

Can anyone tell me where I can get this context value during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to code around the context, why not change the deployment to prevent execution under **Custom Mass Update** ?

Locate the Deployment, move to the **Context Filtering** tab and scroll through the **Execution Context** field looking for the **Custom Mass Update** option and deselect it.

[image: Deployment Example]

Comment: Good idea - same outcome. I updated the deployment as you suggested and ran a mass update while logging the UserEventType. Script still got triggered, eventtype still xedit. Apparently NetSuite doesn't really use this 'Custom Mass Update' attribute.